# Beanio : How to validate a field, depending on another field value?

Tags: java, text-parsing, flat-file, bean-io

I am parsing a fixed length field flat file to a java bean using beanio library.
I have certain validations provided to number of fields.

For one of the field, I need to add a mandatory validation if another field is having a certain value.

Is there a way to attain this requirement through beanio?

Comment: I don't think it is possible to do it out of the box.

Comment: @nicoschl I am also thinking the same way.